# How do I disable italicization in gimli interpretation of markdown?

Tags: markdown, italics, gimli

Some variants of Markdown understand that (say)

/:id/archive_browser/get_file

should not be interpreted as

/:id/archive*browser/get*file

But I can't get gimli to behave in this manner.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first way that comes to mind is to escape the underscores like this.

```
/:id/archive\_browser/get\_file
```

I've tested it with gimli, and it works.